# How to construct a homeomorphism with certain conditions on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-construction, compactification

I am reading the paper "Characterizations of $\beta \mathbb{Q}$ and $\beta \mathbb{R}$ " by Eric Van Douwen. One part of his proof of the Proposition 4 (below) is not clear to me. Suppose $H$ is halfline := $[0; \infty)$.

**How does one construct an autohomeomorphism $h$**, such that it maps disjoint closed intervals to subsets of neighborhoods of some points in the remainder of compactification of the halfline $H$?

I think such atuhomeomorphism should be linear, at least partly, but I haven´t succeed in explicitly contructing any autohomeomorphism that would match the criteria.

Thank you for any help!

[image]

Comment: Note that $h^{-1}[U] \subseteq U$ (my notation) happens only on $\Bbb H$, really, not in the remainder, as $h: \Bbb H \to \Bbb H$ and we're really looking at the part of $U$ that lies inside $\Bbb H$ which is a non-empty open set there, as a compactification is a dense embedding. So inside $\Bbb H \cap U$ we find as many (at most countable) disjoint closed intervals as we have in $\mathcal{A}$ and map them piecewise linearly to each other. It's quite trivial that this can be done. Then simultaneously do the same for $V \cap \Bbb H$ and $\mathcal B$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You really helped again (I think I gonna thank you in my paper haha). The only part I dont see is how $\mathbb{H} \cap U$ has as many disjoint closed intervals as has $\mathcal{A}$ - why is that?

Comment: Also, how can any part of $\mathcal{B}$ be mapped by $h$ into $V$, when $h$ is just $\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$, but $V$ must lay outside of $\mathbb{H}$, else it would not have empty intersection with $U$?

Comment: $V$ also lies partly inside $\Bbb H$ of course for the same reason as $U$ does. $U \cap \Bbb H$ contains an open interval at least so many disjoint closed intervals too, just a lot smaller..